# Google Trends unofficial api tweaking

Tags: python, google-trends

I'm new to python, I'm using the below code to collect " Related queries " for a keyword in Google Trends.

```html
#!/usr/bin/python

import http.client as httplib
import urllib
import requests
import json
import sys
import ast

class pytrends:
 def __init__(self):
  self.cj = requests.get("https://trends.google.com/").cookies
  self.opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj))
  self.opener.addheaders = [
   ("Referrer", "https://trends.google.com/trends/explore"),
   ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21'),
   ("Accept", "text/plain")
  ]
  self.api = {
   "Interest over time": 'https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline/csv?',
   "Interest by region": 'https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/comparedgeo/csv?',
   "Related topics" : 'https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/relatedsearches/csv?',
   "Related queries": 'https://trends.google.com/trends/api/widgetdata/relatedsearches/csv?'
  }
  self.widgets = None
  self.widget_params = []

 def encode_time(self, *args):
  if len(args) == 3:
   return "%04d-%02d-%02d" % args
  elif len(args) == 6:
   return "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d\\:%02d\\:%02d" % args
  else:
   return "all"

 def encode_params(self, params, page):
  params["req"] = json.dumps(params["req"],separators=(',', ':'))
  params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
  if page=="explore":
   params = params.replace('%3A', ':').replace('%2C', ',')
  elif page=="csv":
   params = params.replace("+", "%20")
  return params

 def get_widgets(self, keywords, time="all"):
  params = {
   "hl": "en-US",
   "tz": 240,
   "req": {
   "comparisonItem": [
    {
     "keyword": keyword,
     "geo":"",
     "time": self.encode_time(*(time[0])) + " " + self.encode_time(*(time[1])) if isinstance(time, (list, tuple)) else "all"
    }
    for keyword in keywords ],
    "category": 0,
    "property": ""
   }
  }

  #print "https://trends.google.com/trends/api/explore?" + params

  data = self.opener.open("https://trends.google.com/trends/api/explore?" + self.encode_params(params, "explore")).read().decode('utf8')
  data = data[data.find("{"):]
  data = json.loads(data)
  self.widgets = data["widgets"]
  self.widget_params = [keywords, time]

 def get_params(self, keywords, title="Interest over time", time="all"):
  if not self.widget_params or self.widget_params != [keywords, time]:
   self.get_widgets(keywords, time)

  for widget in self.widgets:
   if widget["title"] == title:
    #if title in ["Related queries"]:
    # widget["request"]["restriction"]["geo"]["country"] = "US"
    return {
     "req":widget["request"],
     "token":widget["token"],
     "tz":240
    }

  return dict()

 def download_report(self, keywords, title="Interest over time", time="all"):
  params = self.get_params(keywords, title, time)
  
  url = self.api[title] + self.encode_params(params, "csv")
  return self.opener.open(url).read().decode('utf8')
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
 

 keywords=sys.argv[1].split(",")
 titles=["Interest over time"]
 time="all"
 for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
  arg = sys.argv[i].split('=')
  if arg[0] == "title":
   titles = arg[1].split(",")
  elif arg[0] == "time":
   time = arg[1]
   if time[0] == '[':
    time = ast.literal_eval(time)
 
 trends = pytrends()
 for title in titles:
  print(trends.download_report(keywords, title, time))
```

```
Examples:
        ./pytrends.py coat,jacket time="[[2017,1,1],[2018,1,1]]" title="Interest over time,Interest by region"
        ./pytrends.py blockchain time="today+5-y"
        ./pytrends.py Google,Microsoft,Apple title="Related queries"

        keywords: comma separated list
            word,word,word

        title: comma separated list
        "Interest over time,Interest by region,Related topics,Related queries"

        time: pick one of [
            "all",
            "now+%d-H" % hours,
            "now+%d-d" % days,
            "today+%d-m" % months,
            "today+%d-y" % years,
            [
                [year, month, day] # start time
                [year, month, day] # end time
            ],
            [
                [year, month, day, hour, minute, second] # start time
                [year, month, day, hour, minute, second] # end time
            ]
        ]
```

I need to tweak this code to be able to collect "Related queries" for a **category** (see [here](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?cat=3&date=2019-01-01%202019-12-31)).

I found this embed code on google trends:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/2152_RC04/embed_loader.js"> 
</script> <script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("RELATED_QUERIES", 
{"comparisonItem":[{"geo":"","time":"2019-01-01 2019-12-31"}],"category":3,"property":""}, 
{"exploreQuery":"cat=3&date=2019-01-01%202019-12- 
31","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"}); </script>
```

For a keyword the embed code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/2152_RC04/embed_loader.js"> 
</script> <script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("GEO_MAP", 
{"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"endgame","geo":"","time":"2019-01-01 2019-12- 
31"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"q=endgame&date=2019-01-01%202019-12- 
31","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"}); </script>
```

So that instead of giving a keyword I can give it a category and get all related queries for that time.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: what changes to make to my python file to get top keywords by category instead of having to give the keyword everytime.

Answer (score 0):

First I would try passing an empty (`''`) keyword. If that does not work, then the following will omit that parameter completely in the formatted query. This should match the embedded widget query you found.

I'll start by showing the existing query formatting in `get_widgets`.

```py
# ...
params = {
    "hl": "en-US",
    "tz": 240,
    "req": {
        "comparisonItem": [
            {
                "keyword": keyword,
                "geo":"",
                "time": self.encode_time(*(time[0])) + " " + self.encode_time(*(time[1])) if isinstance(time, (list, tuple)) else "all"
            }
            for keyword in keywords
        ],
        "category": 0,
        "property": ""
}
# ...
```

You can skip the `keyword` parameter if you do not want it. You will also need to specify the category.

```py
encoded_time = self.encode_time(*(time[0])) + " " + self.encode_time(*(time[1])) if isinstance(time, (list, tuple)) else "all"
if not keyword:
    comparison_item = [{'geo': '', 'time': encoded_time}]
else:
    comparison_item = [{'keyword': kw, geo: '', 'time': encoded_time} for kw in keywords]

params = {
    "hl": "en-US",
    "tz": 240,
    "req": {
        "comparisonItem": comparison_item,
        "category": <category goes here>,
        "property": ""
}
```